# Parametric equation of a rotated circle in 4 dimensions

Tags: differential-geometry, circles, plane-curves, parametrization, dimension-theory-analysis

I'm attending a differential geometry course, and I'm stuck at one part of a question that we've been asked.
The following rotated circle is given in 4 dimensions:

$$x_1x_3 + x_2x_4 = \frac{1}{2}$$

I need its 4-dimensional parameterization, using a $\phi \in [0,2\pi[$ value.

To show that this IS in fact a circle, you can solve the following system of equations to  obtain their intersection:

$$ I. x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2 = 1$$
$$ II. v = z \iff x_1 + ix_2 = x_3 + ix_4$$

Where I. is a 4-dimensional sphere, II. is a plane in 4 dimensions, with the correspondance of
$$\mathbb{C}^2 \simeq \mathbb{R}^4$$
$$z := x_1 + ix_2$$
$$v := x_3 + ix_4$$
I'm including the calculation of this intersetion, just to give you a deeper understanding of the problem, however my question only extends to how to obtain the parametric equation of the above circle.

Note: The intersection of a 4-dimensional sphere and a plane can only give you a 2-dimensional circle, since by definition a 4D sphere is the collection of points equal distance from the origin. When we intersect the sphere with a plane, we apply this definition again, so we must get a circle.

Note 2: As far as I understand, this is a circle that's been rotated 45°'s in the $x_3$, and 45°'s in the $x_4$ direction.

Now I'll include the above mentioned calculation:

$$II. \Rightarrow x_3 = x_1 + ix_2 - ix_4 = x_1 + i(x_2 - x_4)$$
$$I. \Rightarrow x_1^2 + x_2^2 + (x_1 + ix_2 - ix_4)^2 + x_4^2 = 1$$
$$\Rightarrow x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_1^2 - x_2^2 - x_4^2 + 2ix_1x_2 - 2ix_1x_4 + 2x_2x_4 + x_4^2 = 1$$
$$2x_1^2 + 2(ix_1x_2 - ix_1x_4 + x_2x_4) = 1$$
$$x_1^2 + x_1i(x_2-x_4) + x_2x_4 = \frac{1}{2}$$
Since in the first equation of this calculation we assumed that
$$x_3 = x_1 + i(x_2 - x_4) \iff x_3 - x_1 = i(x_2 - x_4)$$
We can substitute to get rid of the imaginary unit:
$$x_1^2 + x_1(x_3 - x_1) + x_2x_4 = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$x_1^2 + x_1x_3 - x_1^2 + x_2x_4 = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$x_1x_3 + x_2x_4 = \frac{1}{2}$$
And we get our original equation.

To get back to my original question, I've tried the parameterization of:
$$C(\phi) = \biggl(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}cos(\phi),\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}cos(\phi),sin(\phi),sin(\phi)\biggr), \phi \in [0,2\pi[$$
But after a long while of calculation it ended up being wrong, because I've got nonsense.
So dear Stack Exchange users, can you help me figure this one out?

Comment: I'll highlight the answer we've figured out below in the comments:
The correct explicit formula for the circle has to be given by 3 equations, and not just 1:
$$x_1^2+x_2^2=\frac12,\ x_1=x_3,\ x_2=x_4$$
This DOES have radius 1, since for any point in 4D, its distance from the origin is:
$$\sqrt{(x_1-0)^2+(x_2-0)^2+(x_3-0)^2+(x_4-0)^2}=1$$
This holds for e.g. for the point:
$$\biggr(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0\biggl)$$
So the parametrization is:
$$\biggr(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}cos(\phi),\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}sin(\phi),\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}cos(\phi),\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}sin(\phi)\biggl)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The single equation you wrote at the beginning does not describe a circle, but a $3$-dimensional object. However, your own proof shows that the following is a circle:

$$
x_1x_3+x_2x_4=\frac12,\ x_1=x_3,\ x_2=x_4.
$$

Or to write it even more simply

$$
x_1^2+x_2^2=\frac12,\ x_1=x_3,\ x_2=x_4.
$$

In other words, you forgot the equality constraints. This should now not be a problem to parametrize.

Comment: The equations of
$$x_1x_3 + x_2x_4 = \frac{1}{2}$$
and
$$ x_1^2+x_2^2=\frac12$$
aren't equivalent, the first describes a pure 4-dimensional object, a rotated circle, the second describes a circle in the $x_1, x_2$ plane.
I have no trouble parametrizing a circle in 2-dimensions, however, I have not learned how to do so for a rotated one.

Comment: You can also see that they're not equivalent, because the 1st equation has radius = 1, since it's part of a 4D sphere with radius 1, and the second one has radius $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: I don't know how a "rotated circle" is a "pure 4-dimensional object". Moreover, a circle in 4D cannot be defined using one equation, since it has codimension 3. It requires three equations, which I gave you, but for some reason you are ignoring the other two. Of course you could add many other pairs of linear equation and still get a circle, but  I chose the ones that your proof seemed to imply.

Comment: Still, the equations of
$$x_1x_3+x_2x_4=\frac12,\ x_1=x_3,\ x_2=x_4$$
and
$$x_1^2+x_2^2=\frac12,\ x_1=x_3,\ x_2=x_4$$
cannot be eqivalent, because the 1st equation has radius 1, since it's part of a 4D sphere with radius 1, and the second one has radius $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. I understand your point but I don't know where contradiction is.

Comment: If a circle lies on a sphere of radius $1$ then it does not necessarily itself have radius $1$. This isn't true even for circles on the sphere in 3D.

Comment: I see, so that implies that the center of
$$x_1x_3+x_2x_4=\frac12,\ x_1=x_3,\ x_2=x_4$$
is NOT the origin. However, the plane that it's part of:
$$II. v = z \iff x_1 + ix_2 = x_3 + ix_4$$
does go through the origin.
How does this circle look like then?

Comment: Since if we intersect a sphere with radius 1, and center origin with a plane that goes through the origin, the resulting intersection, a circle, must also have radius 1. Or is that not how it works if the sphere is 4-dimensional?

Comment: Sorry, I unnecessarily confused you at some point. The correct resolution is that the circle
$$ x_1^2+x_2^2=\frac12, x_1=x_3, x_2=x_4$$
HAS radius $1$ and HAS center at the origin. To see this, we first note, as you did, that the origin lies in the 2D plane of that circle. Moreover the distance from any point on the circle to the origin is
$$\sqrt{(x_1-0)^2+(x_2-0)^2+(x_3-0)^2+(x_4-0)^2}=1.$$

Comment: Oh now I see, for example the point $\biggr( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0 \biggl)$ satisfies the circle equation, and IS distance 1 away from the origin, by the distance formula you've given. Thanks, that helped a lot! So the correct parameterization would be:
$$ \biggr( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} cos(\phi), \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} sin(\phi), \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} cos(\phi), \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} sin(\phi) \biggl) $$
I was pretty close with my original guess.